Problem performing insert using Hibernate entity manager after upgrading hibernate-core dependency version
Up to the following version of hibernate-core
implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.6.0.Alpha1'
it would be possible to perform the following code successfully:
INSERT INTO example_table (geom) 
VALUES (
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
            $dollar${"type":"Point","coordinates":[-34.4214,-15.9216]}$dollar$
        ),
        4326
    )
)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;


Which hibernate would run the following statement:
INSERT INTO example_table (geom) 
VALUES (
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
            $dollar${"type":"Point","coordinates":[-34.4214,-15.9216]}$dollar$
        ),
        4326
    )
)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;;

But after upgrading that dependency to:
implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.6.0.CR1' OR ABOVE, the same query would cause hibernate to try to execute the following statement:
INSERT INTO example_table (geom) 
VALUES (
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
            $dollar$""""""{type:Point,coordinates:[-34.4214,-15.9216]}$dollar$
        ),
        4326
    )
)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;;

Which leads to the following exception: [ERROR: unknown GeoJSON type] [n/a].
Those queries are run using EntityManager.createNativeQuery(query).
Does anyone know why this started happening (multiple double quotes in the query)? I couldn't find anything about it in the release notes. The only way I found to solve this issue was taking off the dollar quote and surrounding the json with single quotes, which is not what I want to do.
This happens to every version above 6.6.0.CR1, including the one used by spring data jpa from spring boot 3.4.x.
edit. 1
I need to use native queries for batch inserts with upsert behavior. Hibernate/JPA does not support operations like ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.

Why are you even using an Alpha1 version? That is pre-beta, especially since version 6.6.3 is already out. At least upgrade to that, next to that why are you manually managing the Hibernate version while you are using Spring Boot? This can lead to you including an unsupported version of Hibernate.

Hello, @M.Deinum, thanks for your reply.  I'm not using Alpha. What I meant is that every version after 6.6.0.Alpha has that problem.

Also, I am managing its version (using 6.5.3.Final) because the one used by spring boot has the problem, every version after 6.6.0.Alpha1 does. Spring boot 3.4.x uses a greater version. I've updated the question.
